# ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID while trinyg to access github

Tags: github, ssl-certificate, kaspersky

I am facing strange issues when trying to access some websites, like github or any search on google. I see:

[image]

I see it with every browser. But other sites are working fine.

My machine date is correctly configured though.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've installed Kaspersky Anti-Virus, and it's issued a root certificate for your system that lets it perform a meddler-in-the-middle attack on every website.  In addition, it's issuing certificates that don't even have a correct date, and so your access to the Internet is broken.

The Git developers don't recommend using any antivirus or firewall on Windows other than the default because this kind of MITM attack breaks Git very frequently in lots of different ways.  Thus, the best choice is to uninstall Kaspersky completely, reboot, and use only Windows Defender.